# Position two textviews around center. (Right and left aligned)

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `ListView` where each line has two words. I would like the two words to be align around the center with a small gap.

Similar to (some random words...):

```
 Please    Help
     me    !!
   This    should
    not    be
     so    hard
```

Each row in the `ListView` consists of two `TextView`s..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:gravity="right" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:gravity="left" />

</LinearLayout>
```